# Can't test on System.Boolean

Tags: c#

This

```
row["active"].GetType().ToString()
```

evals to

```
System.Boolean
```

Why is this an error?

```
if (row["active"]) { ... }
if (row["active"] == true) { ... }
```

I would think that a System.Boolean could be true or false?

Comment: Because `row[string]` returns type `object`, not `boolean` and the `if` block will not automatically convert to type `boolean`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of `row["active"]` is an object, which isn't valid as a boolean predicate. That the value returned is actually a wrapped boolean doesn't matter.

You know that it is a boolean, but the compiler doesn't. What if `row["active"]` would suddenly return a string? Than the expression would be invalid. The .NET runtime binds variables early, on compile time. It doesn't evaluate their types on runtime, like some dynamic languages do.

You have to tell the compiler the value is a boolean by casting it:

```
if ((bool)row["active"]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

`row[string]` returns type `object`, not `boolean` and the `if` block will not automatically convert to type `boolean`.

You could cast yourself like this.

```
if ((bool) row["active"]) { ... }
```

Comment: It doesn't matter who was faster. It matters what is the best answer.

Comment: @LeifNeland - In my defense I had my comment up first :). However Patrick provided a better/more complete answer than I did.

Comment: Allright, both answers were right, but I can only mark one as the preferred.

Comment: Like I said, mark @PatrickHofman 's, out of the 2 it is the more complete one.